# Are ultraviolet LEDs used in consumer lights? (xmas lights)

Tags: led, uv

I took apart a bulb on this strip of purple christmas lights and was surprised to find that the LEDs inside are actually purple 3mm LEDs. Naturally, I looked into some replacements but then the thought crossed my mind of whether or not these are UV emitting, or some mixture to make purple. Looking around online, it seems sort of difficult to find purple LEDs that are "non-ultraviolet". Here's a picture:

Edit: I am also choosing a purple LED to replace the bad lights but am concerned about the health risks. The lights are encased inside of a tinted “globe”. I’ve seen LED’s on amazon around 395nm wavelength.

[image]

Comment: Some of the older white LEDs are ultraviolet with a phosphor, though they nearly universally use blue with a phosphor nowadays.

Comment: I wonder how likely it is that the LED's inside these are UV emitting?

Comment: Most likely UV LEDs are too expensive and dangerous to put on cheap consumer light strings, so that's likely just a purple LED.

Comment: On the other hand, most consumer green laser pointers (even the cheap ones) are actually infrared laser diodes with a bunch of weird crystals to double the frequency of the laser to be green because of the economics of green laser diodes. Incidentally, the cheaper ones can quite hazardous as a result due to mediocre infrared filtering and infrared laser light can leak out.

Comment: Humans can't see UV so what would be the point of using UV LEDs? UV LEDs do exist but they are used for special applications and expensive. Cheap LEDs that emit purple/blue light can be made by using a **blue** LED with a phosphor based coating on the LED chip.

Comment: Exceptionally unlikely to be a UV LED. If it’s purple it’s either blue + red as two separate chips or blue + red phosphor.

Comment: @BobaJFET (which reminds me of the Bobiverse fiction series), if you are just worried about UV as a health issue with these LEDs, I would not worry. Most clear things block UV (most glasses do, though some fused quartz can pass a little.) Sapphire can pass it well. So can diamond. And finally, the LEDs just won't produce it. Not even the violet ones (rather than the purple ones.) On the other hand, mercury and mercury-argon lamps most certainly can emit harmful UV. But that's a whole other thing.

Comment: @BobaJFET Interesting note: Purple and violet aren't the same color perceptions. Variations in luminance impact the color perceptions of each, quite differently. The combination of cone cell responses into color perception are currently believed to be in the posterior inferior temporal cortex (so-called *V4 Complex*) and the populations of glob cells there are biased heavily towards unique hue responses. (FYI, there is also strong evidence (2016ff) that rod cells are **not** in our perception of color in glob cell structures -- a question that wasn't understood as well as it now seems to be.)

Answer (score 3):

A 'purple' LED may not be what you think it is. The human eye cannot distinguish between 'true' purple or violet (visible wavelengths shorter than blue) and a mixture of red and blue light.

Most 'white' LEDs use a blue emitter with a phosphor to convert some of the light to longer wavelengths. To create a purple LED the phosphor just needs to peak in the red part of the band rather than yellow.

Example spectra of [Purple LED globe](https://www.aquayee.com/posts/17727):-

[image]

[image]